# SQL CLR streams data and is unsafe I need a safe solution

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a SQL server C# CLR function that streams results. because of that I open a new connection inside the CLR and because of that I need to create the CLR unsafe. Now I want to move to sql container on linux and there are only safe assemblies allowed.

If there some way to come around that I can stream the data with a context connection? It is no solution to cache all the data as list and return it complete. The amount of data is to much and I will get memory trouble.

Or should I bring my CLR outside of the SQL server as a web service and I call the web service with a CLR? is that possible? sounds strange CLR calls a web service that calls the same sql server and streams the data...

OR is there another idea that I have not focused?

My CLR looks like (shorten pseudo), there are intern more complex classes and code

```
   [SqlFunction
    (
    DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
    IsDeterministic = true,
    IsPrecise = true,
    SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read,
    FillRowMethodName = "FillMethod",
    TableDefinition = ...
    )]
  public static IEnumerable GetData(DateTimeOffset timeRangeStart, DateTimeOffset timeRangeEnd, int maxRecords, int lcid, string filterClause)
  {
    // runs a query to get all need parameters to open a new connection.
    var connectionString = ContextConnectionGetConnectionString();
    using connection = new Connection(connectionString)
    connection.Open();
    var complexScript = CreateTheScript(...);
    var command = connection.CreateCommand(complexScript)
    var streamReader = command.ExecuteReader();

      try
      {
        foreach (var items in readData(streamReader))
        {
          yield return items;
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        CloseStream(streamReader, streamConnection);
        command.Dispose();
      }   
  }
```

I think there's a lot of context missing. Like, what is in complexScript and why can't that be just a normal (i.e. non-CLR) stored procedure (or function)?

the query string contains a sql like language with virtual table names that is parsed and build to work on the current database. The Tables in the database are also splited like segments and with the timerange only the segment tables in that time range values are will be added to the query that is executed at the end.

CLR function is used in other views and from SQL server reports

Comment: I think there's a lot of context missing. Like, what is in `complexScript` and why can't that be just a normal (i.e. non-CLR) stored procedure (or function)? How is your current CLR function called and by whom? From the little that you've shown above, I'm not seeing an advantage of using CLR.

Comment: have added your question to my question part

Comment: What's the point of this code? It seems to be doing nothing more than executing a query and returning the results. You don't need SQLCLR for that. A stored procedure or even raw SQL would do the same, only faster and using less memory. The only way to query is using SQL, so whatever `CreateTheScript` does, in the end it creates a SQL query. Instead of returning the result rows directly to the caller, it loops over them before returning them - the results are being streamed by the database already.

Comment: If you want to tell the database to produce an execution plan that *doesn't* try to buffer to improve performance, you need to use the `OPTION( (FAST FIRST N)` hint. Otherwise you'll still have to wait for the entire query to finish, including any buffering, before SQL Server starts returning rows even to SQLCLR

Comment: `The Tables in the database are also splited like...` you're describing table partitioning, which is available in all supported versions and editions. Querying partitioned tables, eliminating partitions, is transparent. You don't gain in speed either, partitioning is a data management feature. There are far more important performance features like table compression to reduce IO and columnstore indexes. These provide *real* 100x improvements

Comment: you are right the example not shows everything what is in the CLR there are many classes, I have cut the example to the main problem. How I have written, the filterstring contains a sql like query that is parsed and then mapped to the real tables, and the query is executed on tables for that time range. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: The main problem is using SQLCLR to do what SQL Server itself is already doing in a better and faster way

Comment: you are right, but to the time when we implemented the segmentation what is now the partitioning feature it was not as feature in the sql server available. And now it is a question of licenze costs.